# permutation/ arrangement optimization

Tags: optimization, permutations, integer-programming, discrete-optimization

I would like to obtain the optimized arrangement of integers. Let me give a simple example.

Suppose I have a sequence like `1,2,3,4,5` I would like to re-arrange it according to a given metric function.
Suppose in this case, the metric function is $g(x)$ where $g(x) = \min(|x_{i+1}-x_i|)$. So in our case,  $g(x) = \min(\{2-1, 3-2, 4-3, 5-4\}) = 1$

if we have $x = \{2,5,3,1,4\}\implies g(x) = \min(\{|5-2|, |3-5|, |1-3|, |4-1|\}) = \min(\{3,2,2,3\})=2$

Now Suppose we want to re-arrage the vector such that we maximize this metric function, how can we formulate the problem? Is there a way to solve this without trying all permutations? In my problem, I have a vector of length n and a different metric function which is quite complicated than the one given above.

Let me know if more information is needed

### EDIT:

We could think of the problem as $$\underset{x}{\arg\max} ~g(x)~~s.t.~ x_i\in \mathbb N, \mathbf{x} = \{1,...,N\}$$

Can this work? If so how can we proceed?

Comment: Your example metric function is easily linearizable.  What is your real metric function?

Comment: @RobPratt the metric i have is the manhattan distance between the points. ie, $x$ is a vector which given a parameter N, you can write it in a column major format and take the manhattan distances of the points, then obtain the minimum of those distances. eg. if $x=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $N=2$ then we have $x = \begin{pmatrix}1&4\\2&5\\3&6\end{pmatrix}$ and then compute the manhattan distance $d(x) = \begin{array}{c|ccc}&1&2&3\\\hline1&0&2&4\\2&2&0&2\\3&4&2&0\end{array}$. Then ignoring the diagonal, I look for the minimum ie 2. Thus $g(x)=2, \quad\text{given } ~N=2$

Comment: @RobPratt the aim is to use any distance metric function really. instead of manhattan distance, look at the euclidean distance, for example. Hope this helps

Comment: $x$ is $(n/N)\times N$, and $d$ is square of size $n/N$ and symmetric?

Comment: @RobPratt yes $x$ is $n\times N$ vector and $d$ is always symmetric. Only interested in the monimum distance in d. So whether you compute only the lower or upper triangle is fine. The metric function $g(x)=\min d(x)$. The aim is to rearrange $x$ such that $g(x)$ is maximized.

Comment: In your example, $n=6$, $N=2$, and $x$ is $(n/N) \times N = 3 \times 2$.

Comment: @RobPratt yes you are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the problem via mixed integer nonlinear programming as follows.  Let $m$ be the number of rows and $n$ the number of columns.  For $i\in \{1,\dots,m\}$, $j\in \{1,\dots,n\}$, and $k\in \{1,\dots,mn\}$, let binary decision variable $y_{i,j,k}$ indicate whether $x_{i,j}=k$.  Let $z$ represent the minimum distance over row pairs $(i_1,i_2)$. The problem is to maximize $z$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_k y_{i,j,k} &= 1 &&\text{for all $i,j$} \tag1 \\
\sum_{i,j} y_{i,j,k} &= 1 &&\text{for all $k$} \tag2 \\
\sum_k k y_{i,j,k} &= x_{i,j} &&\text{for all $i,j$} \tag3 \\
z &\le \sum_j |x_{i_1,j}-x_{i_2,j}| &&\text{for all $i_1,i_2$ with $i_1<i_2$} \tag4 \\
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ assigns exactly one value per cell.
Constraint $(2)$ assigns exactly one cell per value.
Constraint $(3)$ enforces $y_{i,j,k}=1 \iff x_{i,j}=k$.
Constraint $(4)$ enforces the maximin objective; you can replace the right-hand side with any distance formula for row pairs.

For $m=3$ and $n=2$, here is an optimal solution, with $z=|6-5|+|4-2|=3$:
$$
x = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &3 \\
6 &4 \\
5 &2 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thanks so much for taking your time to do this. I will definitely accept this as a solution. In the meantime, could you please provide some links/boks to rwad on this kind of maximization? I would appreciate